# Grails, Vaadin 7 and SpringSecurity: authorization not working

Tags: grails, spring-security, vaadin

I have followed [this](http://www.epseelon.com/2011/02/23/grails-vaadin-and-spring-security-core/) link to implement app security with Grails, Vaadin 7 and Spring Security. The authentication part works, but it looks like authorization doesn't.
I've created a service as simple as that:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
class WelcomeService {
    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def sayHello() {
        return "Hello, ADMIN!"
    }
}
```

and a user with `"ROLE_USER"`, but each time I call

`Notification.show(Grails.get(WelcomeService).sayHello())` the message is displayed, but an `AccessDeniedException` should be thrown instead.

Do you have any ideas why this might be happening?

---

**UPD**: The only solution I could think of so far is altering the service code like this:

```
def sayHello = {
    if (!springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities().contains(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"))){
        throw new AccessDeniedException("You are not authorized to do this!")
    }
    return "Hello, ADMIN!"
}
```

But injecting a `springSecurityService` into every service class and adding this code to every method is really embarassing. How can I do it in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it has to be like `@Secured("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` for controllers and all the rest need an ACL plugin to work.